# Using variables as names for other variables in Java

Tags: java

Alright, I am not completely sure that I worded the title right, but I want to use an int variable to define another int to go through a method.  In other words, I want to be able to have the int/name/thingy variable go through a ++ statement, and then the next variable would go through the method.  Is this possible?

Comment: Like... a pointer? Can you show us in pseudo-code or another language what you're thinking?

Comment: Could you provide a bit of pseduo code to explain what you want to do?

Comment: it could be, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Kylar I only really know java...  Anyways I am trying to make a virtual grid for a Conways Game of Life thing, and am debating where and how to store the variables.

Comment: And I haven't tried yet, just wanted to know if I would be spinning my wheels or not.

Comment: I think, he needs reflection.

Comment: for your case, reflection could be your friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reflection.

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0125__Reflection/Catalog0125__Reflection.htm

or see to have an idea.

[Setting variables by name in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276555/setting-variables-by-name-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

An int array might solve your problem. The array stores your ints ("variables"), another one runs throught the index (your ++ operation):

```
int[] values = loadValuesInArray();  // some magic to get the populated array
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
   myMagicMethod(values[i]);         // calling the method with int values 
}
```

---

If you need *named* variables, then you can use a map:

```
Map<String, Integer> variables = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
variables.put("a", 1);
variables.put("b", -10);
variables.put("c", 25);

myMagicMethod(variables.get("b"));  // calls method with value from "variable" b
```

Comment: Yes, I am currently saying this will probably be the best option.  There is another for block, which you can do something for each variable in the array.  +1 for a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to create a new variable with a name, stored in another variable, then reflection is a way to go.

```
String varName = "x";

Point2D point = new Point(15, 2);
Integer val = (Integer)Point.class.getDeclaredField(varName).get(point);
assert val == 15;
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly want to be using something like a `Map` or `List` (essentially a dense map with a small positive `int` key).

Answer (score 0):

You say "I want to use an int variable to define another int" do you mean something like

```
int a = 0; //declare a new variable a of type int and assign it to zero
a b = 0;   //declare a new variable b of type a which is an int and assign it to zero
```

From what you said, that is what it appears you are saying. If that is the case, I do not think you can do that. My memory says that there is a method that allows you to determine the type of an object, but to use that as a declaration of another variable... I don't know if you can do that.

Comment: No, not really.  I want to say "use the value of x to be the name for Y", and there is like 64 Y's, each with its own value