# How to use the value of a String as a variable name

Tags: java

My question is suppose there is a String variable like `String abc="Shini";`.

So is it possible to use `"Shini"` as new variable name by some automatic means not by explicit typing.

```
String abc = "Shini"; 
String Shini = "somevale";
```

Comment: no, it is not possible.

Comment: what do you mean by automatic means ?

Comment: Yes. You can use. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276555/setting-variables-by-name-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Variables must be declared at compile time, so no it is not possibile at runtime
Best thing it comes to my mind is to use it as a map key

```
String abc = "Shini";
Map<String, String> myMap = new Hashmap<>();
myMap.put(abc, "something");
```

Then myMap.get("Shini") will give "something".

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use.

```
class Foo {
    private int lorem;
    private int ipsum;

    public Foo(){}

    public setAttribute(String attr, int val) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Field field = getClass().getDeclaredField(attr);
        field.setInt(this, val);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Foo f = new Foo();
        f.setAttribute("lorem", 1);
        f.setAttribute("ipsum", 2);   
    }
}
```

I did not compile this code. Please check if this can have minor mistakes.