# I want to use elements of an array as variables but how?

Tags: java, arrays

```
 char [] abc ={a,b,c};//  The array      //   1)
    for(int i = 0; i < abc.length; i++) {  //for loop   //  2)
        String abc[i] = "yukarı";   // 3)
    }
```

*/
        1) I need variables for example: a, b, c. But if I put them in an array(I need to reach them with numbers) they are not variables as you can see.

2) I will assign the elements of abc array to strings automatically. But java does not accept that
               String abc[i] = "yukarı";
               abc[i] is not supported in here. Java want to see
               String x = "yukarı";

3) I need these a, b, c variables in array because I need to reach them with numbers. If ı could assign a number to a
        string value all my problems were solved.

Can you suggest another way or help? 
        If Is there any fail for my explanation sorry about that. Thanks for your helps.

Comment: I don't even have a clue what you're asking. `It did not work as an explanation.` - what was the explanation? In what way did it not work? What did you expect and what did you get?

Comment: @Thomas To me it sounds like he wants to store multiple Strings in an array. At least as far as I understand his "explanation".

Comment: Btw, `abc` is a `char` array and thus you can't assign a string to it. Why not `String[] abc = ...`?

Comment: This seems to be a [xyproblem](http://xyproblem.info/). Can you specify what you really want to do?

Answer (score 0):

1). In here you define the array as a char array. (can consider as a collection of chars) So you can not add a string to that. So you can write as follows,

```
String [] abc ={"a","b","c"};
for(int i = 0; i < abc.length; i++) {
    abc[i] = "yukarı";   // like String a = "yukarı";
```

It seams that you have less knowledge in java arrays.So refer [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arrays.htm) link for more details.

2). And you can use **reflection** to do so. please refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276555/setting-variables-by-name-in-java)

Comment: I'm not sure that answers what he's asking - and I'm not sure I understand what he's asking either. There's just that `I want to use all elements in abc like variables.` part which doesn't seem to fit.

Comment: @Thomas i think he consider abc[0] as a variable. isn't it ?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure - I guess he wants `a` etc. to be variables as well. Btw, `String abc[i] = "yukarı";` won't work since you can't redefine the type (let alone of a single array element).

Answer (score 0):

try the below

```
String [] abc ={a,b,c};
    //abc[0] = "yukarı";  //I want to use all elements in abc like variables.
    for(int i = 0; i < abc.length; i++) {
        abc[i] = "yukarı";   // like String a = "yukarı";
```